# QBO3 - Show/Hide form elements using ImportFormTemplate GUI

Tags: forms, qbo3

I'm building an ImportFormTemplate in QBO3 (Quandis Business Objects), and I want to show or hide a Question on the basis of another Question's answer.

What is the correct syntax for testing form field values in the Dependency attribute of a Question?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to test the value of a form field is:

{Name}{operator}{value}

Notes:

- your *Name* value should match the *Name* field in the target field
- to test equality, use a single `=` operator
- quotation marks are not required for test values

Example:
If you have a dropdown called *test1*, you can show/hide another field called *test2* on the basis of `test1=yes`.

test1 setup:

[image]

test2 setup:
[image]